# Very slow motion smooth rendering - cocos2d-x

Tags: rendering, cocos2d-x

I have a a white circle that I move on a black background very slowly. When I look very carefully, I see that the while moving the edge of the circle is jittering. In my opinion it is because the next row/col of pixels becomes white from black where the circle should be rendered and as the pixel has some width I see some abrupt advance of the edge toward the direction. Ideally, this should not be visible if I would not have pixel discretization. But on the other hand a have a video sample with such a slow motion and my monitor renders it without any jumps on the edge. Hence, I think that it is because of not the fact that pixel have finite sizes but I render wrongly. How I can solve the problem? Any trick, flag?

**EDIT:** Here is the code I have used:

```
Sprite* bg = Sprite::create("gfx/letter_background.png");
addChild(bg, 100);
bg->runAction(MoveBy::create(80, Vec2(500, 500)));
```

wherer the `.png` I have used is a white circle attached below:

[image]

You don't see the image above as it is white :)

Comment: We can't know if you're rendering incorrectly without your render code.

Comment: I use Cocos2d-x game engine and in Edit I will include my code @StrongJoshua